# Pass JSON Object to another page

Tags: javascript, json

I am developing Web page using HTML 5. The page has Add details button to add multiple contact details. When user clicks Add Button in details page , this info needs to be displayed in Main Page in Tabular format. All these information needs to be saved in database only after user clicks Submit button in the Main Page only.

Below is my java script for main page

```
var jsonContact = [{"name" :"" ,"email":"","mobile":""}];
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to pass some data across pages the best approach would be to use localStorage/sessionStorage (the only difference is that localStorage has no expiration date, sessionStorage is self-describable).

```
var jsonContact = [{"name" :"" ,"email":"","mobile":""}];
sessionStorage.setItem('contactOptions', JSON.stringify(jsonContact));
sessionStorage.getItem('contactOptions');
```

Dont forget to parse json back:)

Comment: Can you provide how i can add item to JSON in detail page . Sorry I am new to  json objects

Comment: Broadly speaking JSON is nothing more than a regular javascript object. To store you just have to stringify it and store as string then when you want to treat this as object again you just parse it. Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/frx0d2ea/4/

Comment: It is not working... may be because  I am using mowbly platform